# Python, passing list into recursive function

Tags: python, list, function, recursion

https://leetcode.com/problems/path-sum-ii/

This question is from Leetcode, the code is working but I was really confused about how the list is modified in recursive functions. I mean, the list is passed by reference, right? So, once the value is appended to list in deeper recursive calls should persist in shallow functions? But my "ls" list here doesn't have values that were added in the latter part of the recursion calls. I really need to understand how lists are passed into recursive functions and how they get modified.

```
class Solution:

def dfs(self, root, sum, ls, res):
    if not root.left and not root.right and sum == root.val:
        ls.append(root.val)
        res.append(ls)
    print(ls)
    if root.left:
        self.dfs(root.left, sum-root.val, ls+[root.val], res)
    if root.right:
        self.dfs(root.right, sum-root.val, ls+[root.val], res)

def pathSum(self, root: TreeNode, su: int) -> List[List[int]]:
    if not root:
        return []
    ls = []
    ans = []
    self.dfs(root, su, ls, ans)
    return ans
```

Comment: You're not passing 'ls` to recursive calls.  You're passing `ls+[root.val]` - that expression creates a brand new list object. Modifying the result of that expression in deeper calls has no effect on the `ls` you started with.

Comment: Silly me. I understand it now!
I was really struggling to explain the question. Thanks!